# Select only if all values are identical for a given id

Tags: sql, oracle

Consider the following table

```
C1    || C2  ||
---------------
1     || a   ||
1     || b   ||
2     || a   ||
3     || b   ||
3     || b   ||
```

I would like to select all rows R with the same C1 value such that all the C2 values are equal.
In my example, I will:

- **not** get the first 2 rows (because they have the same C1=1 value but different C2=a|b values)
- get the third row (no duplicate C1)
- get the 4th and 5th row (in a single row) as they have the same C1=3 value and same C2=b value.

I have written this request: `SELECT C1, C2 FROM mytable group by C1, C2 having count(*) = 1;`
but this doesn't work: I get all rows...

I know why: the `group by` is also done on C2, but I don't know how to do otherwise...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select c1, max(c2) as c2_value
from your_table
group by c1
having count(distinct c2) = 1
```

Use `count(distinct c2)` to count only **different** values.
Also I used `max(c2)` instead of `c2` since you need to aggregate a column if you don't group by it.

To get all values of `c1` anyway you could do:

```
select c1, 
       case when count(distinct c2) = 1 
            then max(c2) 
            else null
       end as c2_value
from your_table
group by c1
```

Comment: This works great and that makes me wonder... How could I get all my C1 values with either "null" if my requirements are not fulfilled or C2 if it is ? 
Getting something like: 1 NULL | 2 a | 3 b

Answer (score 1):

Apart from using the `GROUP BY`, you can also achieve the desired result using `NOT EXISTS` and `ROW_NUMBER` analytical function as follows:

```
select distinct c1, c2
  from your_table t
 where not exists (select 1 from your_table t1
                    where t.c1 = t1.c1
                      and t.c2 <> t1.c2);

select distinct c1, c2 
  from (select c1, c2, count(1) over (partition by c1,c2) as cnt
          from your_table)
 where cnt = 1;
```